# modifing CYK to compute the number of different parsing trees of a given sentence

Tags: trees

Given a CFG in Chomsky Normal Form and a sentence s.
I want to count the number of different parsing trees that parses s.
assuming I know how to change the CYK algorithm so it would count the number of parsing trees, how can I determine if one tree X is different then tree Y? obviously it can be done in a naive way that I would save all my current parse trees and for every new tree I would check if it already exists but it's time-consuming and space-consuming as It requires to save all the previous parsing trees in a data structure... I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Use the exact same recurrences as in CYK, but keep track of the number of parse trees instead of just whether there is a part tree.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i believe this is not answering my question, I did modify the CYK to count the number of parsing trees, but not count the number of *different* parsing trees as required...my issue is determine efficiently if tree X equals tree Y

Comment: Do you have an example in which your current approach is double-counting parse trees?

Comment: isn't it a problem if i have 2 rules of the form X->AB Y->AB? i might not fully understand what is the meaning of 2 different parsing trees, for my understanding 2 parsing trees are equal if we run in-order traversal and for every node x in tree X it equals to node y in tree Y in the same order...is it right?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? That is, a CFG and a bad run of your modified CYK algorithm. Add it to your post.

Comment: well, I can't find but I also can't prove my self that every parse tree is unique.

Comment: Perhaps you're not clear on the definition of when two parse trees are different. A parse tree is an ordered tree (that is, the children of each node are ordered) in which every internal node is labelled by a nonterminal and every leaf is labelled by a terminal. Two parse trees are the same if they are the same as ordered labelled trees.

Comment: Try proving inductively that your modified CYK does count distinct parse trees.

Comment: trying to prove it, does the inductive need to be on the hight of the parsing tree?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. You can do induction on many things.